# trigger.io Can't debug on iOS device

Tags: ios, trigger.io

I am developing an app with trigger.io using some native plugins for iOS and i am having issues debugging my application. 
The app is successfully transferred to the device, the app starts up and is suddenly terminated. The trigger io console output ends with:

```
[INFO] (lldb) connect
[INFO] Process 0 connected
[INFO] (lldb) waiting for connection event
[INFO] No connect event, assuming we are already connected
[INFO] (lldb) run
[INFO] error: process launch failed: failed to get the task for process 386
```

[Here is a gist of the full output](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9441db7c272e41417b3f)

My lldb version is lldb-320.4.124.10 . 
Forge tools running at version 3.3.82, Xcode 6.0.2, the device is running iOS 8.0.2

Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We've noticed that sometimes lldb & ios-deploy can get themselves into a hung state, especially if you have multiple `forge run` commands active.

To see if this is the issue here, try running:

```
lsof -i:12345
```

Try killing all processes listed and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This error also appears when you pick an ad-hoc or other production provisioning profile. Make sure that your code signing is for development.